# Emacs not displaying some Devanagari characters correctly

Tags: fonts, display

I am using Emacs for OSX 24.4 on El Capitan. I am writing a text in Devanagari in LaTeX mode, which I compile using the XeTeX engine. I have changed the font set for Devanagari to Sanskrit 2003 in Emacs. While most characters (including complex ones) are displayed correctly, some simple ones are only displayed "half". For example, only the **left half**  (about the middle vertical line) of the character के is displayed in Emacs! (Sorry! Couldn't figure out how to load an image). This is also true for कं, फे, फं, कु, फु etc. का, फा etc. display correctly. When I place my cursor immediately to the right of these characters which display incorrectly, I see the negative of the un-displayed half in the background. Can anyone please tell me what is going on and how to correct it?

PS: This is not a font problem as Sanskrit 2003 is a very extensive font for Devanagari and works fine elsewhere. I have also tried other Devanagari fonts by changing the font set in my .emacs file and the problem persists.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: An update. The mac-ports version of Emacs (railway-cat) does not have this problem. Probably has something to do with better Apple Core Text support. Folks using Emacs to type Devanagari should check out this version.